# Brave browser has a user interface problem

Tags: apt, package-management, software-uninstall, purge, brave

My Brave browser has a user interface problem. When I access various websites, the website's appearance is incomplete, including even in the Brave settings page itself.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and have tried to uninstall both brave-browser and brave-keyring, but after reinstalling it https://brave.com/linux/, Brave remembered all the configurations I had set (such as bookmarks and favorited pages) then of course the problem persists.

```
sudo apt remove brave-browser brave-keyring
sudo apt purge brave-browser brave-keyring
rm -rf ~/.config/BraveSoftware
rm -rf ~/.cache/BraveSoftware 
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-*.list
```

Here is an example image of the problem I encountered. Is there anyone who knows how to fix it? I really like this browser and a lot of my work is saved in it.

Facebook:

[image: Facebook]

Gmail 1:

[image: Gmail 1]

Gmail 2:

[image: Gmail 2]

Settings:

[image: Settings]

Comment: Probably the wrong place to post it, as Brave is not Ubuntu. I'd file a bug report or ask on a relevant forum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Brave is based on Chrome. maybe this helps: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1442633

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least on several of the machines we tested, the problem can be bypassed by removing each affected user's GPUCache:

~/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/GPUCache$

I.E.:

~/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/$ rm -rf GPUCache/

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache as you said. Now it's back to work as before.

You're awesome, you've saved me a lot, thank you.

Comment: worked perfectly! i had the same problem

Comment: I had the same issue and work fine to me. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!